# What is known about recent zero day flaw with Tails up to this point in time and is Tails able to keep us anonymous from a global adversary?

Tags: anonymity, tor, zero-day

Following is a excerpt from COMPUTERWORLD

> Yesterday, in talking about the zero-day vulnerability in Tails,
>   Exodus Intelligence wrote:
>       "We publicized the fact that we’ve discovered these issues for a very simple reason: no user should put full trust into any particular
>   security solution. By bringing to light the fact that we have found
>   verifiable flaws in such a widely trusted piece of code, we hope to
>   remind the Tails user base that no software is infallible. Even when
>   the issues we’ve found are fixed by the Tails team, the community
>   should keep in mind that there are most certainly other flaws still
>   present and likely known to others."

What is known about recent zero day flaw with Tails up to this point in time, and is Tails able to keep us anonymous from a global adversary?

Following please find COMPUTERWORLD and EXODUS links:

http://blogs.computerworld.com/malware-and-vulnerabilities/24177/zero-day-broker-exploits-vulnerability-i2p-de-anonymize-tails-users

http://blog.exodusintel.com/2014/07/23/silverbullets_and_fairytails/

Comment: Roya - you have already answered this question over on Tor.SE (https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/3703/245). Not sure why you have asked it here. In any case, with a couple of questions on it there, I'll close this one.